# can we write before & after block to a particular test case (it) of mocha

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js

Can I write something write below? Can I declare before method to a particular test case like we use to do in describe block.

```
describe('demo test suite', function(){
 it('demo test case one', function(){.....})
 it('demo test case two', function(done){
   before(function(){
     //Do some operation only for this particular test case
   })
   //Do some operation again    
 })
})
```

Answer (score 4):

Your intentions are little bit unclear to me, but you can nest describe functions:

```
describe('demo test suite', function(){
 it('demo test case one', function(){.....})
 describe('demo test case two', function(done){
   before(function(){
     //Do some operation
   })
   it('....', function(){
     //Do some operation again
   })     
 })
})
```

Comment: I want to do some before operation only for that particular test case(it)